# Cross Teams Visualizations

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, measure

Hi StackOverflow Masters,

I would like to aks about your help to resolve my PowerBI issue.

My task is to create visualization that shows projects where is multiple teams and shows some differentiation for those teams.
I have few tables: Projects, Employees, EmployeeBookings,Teams, Calendar.
I've created a meassure that I use in 100% stacked bar chart.
I need to be able to filter by team name (from Team table), employee name(from Employee table) and fiscal year(from Calendar table). My solution works fine for filter by team and fiscal year but not show expected result when I filter by resource name. If I choose John John, for example, my visualization should show projects where his team has worked or still working with the other teams they collaborate on those projects.
Right now visualization shows projects he has worked on considering only his team.
I would add that filtering must work for multiple selections from different slicers

Visualization when I'm filtering by Teams:

[image: Filtering by Team]

Result when I'm filtering by resource name:

[image: Filtering by resource name]

My messure used in visualization.

```
Count Cross Team 6 = 
VAR SelectedTeams = VALUES ( Teams[Name] )
VAR SelectedEmployees = VALUES ( Employees[Name] )
VAR SelectedTeamsAndEmployees = UNION ( SelectedTeams, SelectedEmployees )

VAR a =
    SUMMARIZE (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            ALLSELECTED ( EmployeeBookings ),
            "Projects", RELATED ( Projects[Name] ),
            "Team", RELATED ( Employees[Team] ),
            "Employee", RELATED ( Employees[Name] )
        ),
        [ID Project],
        [Projects],
        [Team],
        [Employee]
    )

VAR b =
    COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( a, [Projects] IN VALUES ( Projects[Name] ) ) )

RETURN
    IF (
        ISFILTERED ( Teams[Name] ) && COUNTROWS ( SelectedTeamsAndEmployees ) > 0,
        IF (
            b > 1,
            COUNTROWS (
                FILTER (
                    a,
                    [Projects]
                        IN VALUES ( Projects[Name] )
                            && [Team] IN SelectedTeamsAndEmployees
                )
            )
        ),
        IF (
            ISFILTERED ( Employees[Name] ) && COUNTROWS ( SelectedTeamsAndEmployees ) > 0,
            COUNTROWS (
                FILTER (
                    a,
                    [Projects]
                        IN VALUES ( Projects[Name] )
                            && [Employee] IN SelectedTeamsAndEmployees
                )
            ),
            IF (
                b > 1,
                COUNTROWS (
                    FILTER (
                        a,
                        [Projects]
                            IN VALUES ( Projects[Name] )
                                && [Team] IN VALUES ( Employees[Team] )
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
```

This is my fictional model that reflects the situation in my real project.
[image: My dummy model]

Link if anyone would like to download pbix file.
[pbix file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/18fYed6tk1EF4K6QKcelrPik7eZHDBbS_/view?usp=sharing)

I've tried to change my measure to include a section to filter by resource, but I don't know if I'm able to somehow incorporate the filtering option into my measure.
I tried to create an additional table where I collect columns from the Teams, Project, EmployeeBookings and Employee tables, connect by a relationship to the Projects table and test if the filtering works if I use the columns from the newly created table in the slicer.

If anyone could help solve this issue, I would be very grateful.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: What would you like to see when "John John" is selected?

Comment: Hello @SamNseir,

I would like to see the same view (if I understand it correctly myself) as when filtering using teams. 
Since John John is on the Avengers team then when you select him it should show projects where he and other people are working. That is, the bar should have a division by color where his team is shown and another one that works in the same project. This is what the visualization of people/teams and other people/teams that are working in a particular project is supposed to show.

Comment: @SamNseir could you help :)?

Comment: The bar chart - what number are you trying to show? Number of Employees in a team on a project?

Comment: @SamNseir This can be the number of employees in a team in a project, but if it is easiest to show the number of teams in a project, it is valuable. 
Currently, I am trying to somehow calculate the number of employees in a team in a project and on a bar with colors to show the differentiation into teams.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were almost there. The issue is your Employee slicer was coming from the `Employees` table where the `Team` column was used in the chart legend. So as you slice on `Employee` it will also slice on `Team` - meaning you will never see outside/cross teams.

Steps to get you going.

**1. Create a new disconnected table just for the Employee slicer**

```
Slicer Employee = SUMMARIZECOLUMNS(Employees[ID Employee], Employees[Name])
```

Then update your slicer to use this new table (`Slicer Employee[Name]`)

**2. Update your Measure to refer to the `Slicer Employee` table**

```
Count Cross Team 6 = 
  VAR SelectedTeams = VALUES ( Teams[Name] )
  VAR SelectedEmployees = VALUES ( 'Slicer Employee'[Name] )
  VAR SelectedTeamsAndEmployees = UNION ( SelectedTeams, SelectedEmployees )

  VAR a =
    SUMMARIZE (
        ADDCOLUMNS (
            ALLSELECTED ( EmployeeBookings ),
            "Projects", RELATED ( Projects[Name] ),
            "Team", RELATED ( Employees[Team] ),
            "Employee", RELATED ( Employees[Name] )
        ),
        [ID Project],
        [Projects],
        [Team],
        [Employee]
    )

  VAR b =
    COUNTROWS ( FILTER ( a, [Projects] IN VALUES ( Projects[Name] ) ) )

RETURN
  SWITCH( TRUE(),
    ISFILTERED( Teams[Name] ) && COUNTROWS ( SelectedTeamsAndEmployees ) > 0 && b > 1,
        COUNTROWS (
            FILTER (
                a,
                [Projects]
                    IN VALUES ( Projects[Name] )
                        && [Team] IN SelectedTeamsAndEmployees
            )
        ),
    
    ISFILTERED ( 'Slicer Employee'[Name] ) && COUNTROWS ( SelectedTeamsAndEmployees ) > 0,
        COUNTROWS (
            FILTER (
                a,
                [Projects]
                    IN VALUES ( Projects[Name] )
                        && [Employee] IN SelectedTeamsAndEmployees
            )
        ),
    
    b > 1,
        COUNTROWS (
            FILTER (
                a,
                [Projects]
                    IN VALUES ( Projects[Name] )
                        && [Team] IN VALUES ( Employees[Team] )
            )
        )
  )
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your solution. 
Unfortunately I have to show the projects and the teams that work in them even when I filter using the slicer with the employee's name.

I came up with this solution. I created a virtual array
Assist | Cross Projects. 
Then I have a measure that counts the rows in this table depending on what period it filters for. 

In the legend field in the chart, I use the team name from the additional table created. 

I connected the Teams table to the Projects table with a one to many relationship(in the Projects table I added a Team ID column).

Comment: At this point, the chart shows what it wants. 
When I select Jose Jose it shows nothing because Jose Jose has only one project.
It reacts to filter Team, Fiscal Year and Employee Name - showing the project in question and with a color breakdown of the teams that are working on it.

Comment: Link to my latest version. On "Assist table" page is my solution. What you think about that? 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Y_67BCibtZDup2zcN4-gC6ZQOembbyYc/view?usp=sharing

Comment: The main answer to your problem was to have a separate table for your slicer and your chart legend. In terms of how/what gets filtered with what combination of slicers was down to you. You could really benefit in normalizing your model to a "Star Schema"

Comment: Thanks for your time. Your hints guided me to the solution. I will stay with my solution for the moment :)